# Configuring Redirect URLs for External Login (Facebook, Google) in React Native Amplify App

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, authentication, expo, aws-amplify

I am developing a React Native application using Amplify for authentication. I want to integrate external login mechanisms like Facebook and Google. However, I am unsure about the correct redirect URLs to use in the Amplify configuration for these providers.
I'm talking about the field to fill inside the amplify console for the redirect url

thanks a lot

(using react native expo)

Comment: You can add a "scheme" in your app.json (for expo)